# JavaScript: Why is the output false?

Tags: javascript, object, output, equality

```js
console.log(`${window === this} (window === this)`)
console.log(`${window === self} (window === self)`)
console.log(`${this === self} (this === self)`)

console.log(`${window === this === self} (window === this === self)`)
```

Why is `window === self === this` false in JavaScript

Comment: because `a === b === c` is equivalent to `(a === b) === c`, thus `true === c` which is obviously wrong if `c` is not boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't chain equality operators in such a way in javascript.
`window === this === self` is actually the same as: `(window === this) === self` where the parentheses is evaluated first. In other words `window === this === self` equals `true === self` which evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `true` is not equal to `this`.

This expression:

```js
window === self === this
```

Is equivalent to:

```js
true === this
```

Which is false, because `this` is not a boolean.